# Pattern matching map with optional keys

Tags: elixir

I have a function which receives a map with many keys, some of them are optional. How can I write the function signature comprehending the map while allowing the optional keys to default to something?

```rb
def handle_my_map(%{text: text, 
                    print_times: print_times, # this I want to default to 2
                    color: color # this I want to default to "Blue"
  }) do
  Enum.each(1..print_times, fn (_) -> IO.puts ["(", color, "): ", text] end)
end

Test.handle_my_map(%{text: "here", print_times: 5, color: "Red"})
# (Red): here
# (Red): here
# (Red): here
# (Red): here
# (Red): here

handle_my_map(%{text: "there"})
# => MatchError!
```

I would like it to be:

```rb
handle_my_map(%{text: "where", print_times: 3})
# (Blue): where
# (Blue): where
# (Blue): where
handle_my_map(%{text: "there"})
# (Blue): there
# (Blue): there
```

Something like ruby's keyword arguments:

```rb
def handle_my_map(text: nil, print_times: 2, color: 'Blue')
```

Comment: this `handle_my_map/1` takes one parameter?

Comment: @Зелёный - yes, a single map parameter

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `Map.merge/2`:

```rb
defmodule Handler do
  @defaults %{print_times: 2, color: "Blue"}

  def handle_my_map(map) do
    %{text: text, print_times: times, color: color} = merge_defaults(map)
    Enum.each(1..times, fn (_) -> IO.puts ["(", color, "): ", text] end)
  end

  defp merge_defaults(map) do
    Map.merge(@defaults, map)
  end
end
```

If you want to allow nils, you can use `Map.merge/3` and change `merge_defaults/1` to:

```rb
defp merge_defaults(map) do
  Map.merge(@defaults, map, fn _key, default, val -> val || default end)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Do you also have a suggestion for deep merge?

Comment: If all values are maps, you can do something similar to what is done here: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/mix/lib/mix/config.ex#L192-L196 If not, you just need to check if both values are maps and then call Map.merge/2.

Comment: To clarify, "allow nils" means overwrite nils with the default. Btw, this answer acts as a nice doc for `Map.merge` because the doc doesn't exist in the Elixir installation yet.

Comment: @UriAgassi: the `setVals` method in [`elins`](https://github.com/tycho01/elins) acts as a lens performing a deep merge. Disclaimer, I just wrote it, but Googled in here first while trying to find existing implementations. That being said, non-lens implementations as José suggested may be simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably go with something like this:

```rb
defmodule Handler do
  @defaults %{print_times: 2, color: "Blue"}

  def handle_my_map(map) do
    %{text: text, print_times: times, color: color} = Dict.put_new(map, @defaults)
    Enum.each(1..times, fn (_) -> IO.puts ["(", color, "): ", text] end)
  end
end
```

If you need to handle `nil` values with existing keys, you can do:

```rb
defmodule Handler do
  @defaults %{print_times: 2, color: "Blue"}

  def handle_my_map(map) do
    %{text: text, print_times: times, color: color} = @defaults
    |> Dict.merge(map)
    |> Enum.into %{}, fn
      {key, nil} -> {key, @defaults[key]}
      {key, val} -> {key, val}
    end

    Enum.each(1..times, fn (_) -> IO.puts ["(", color, "): ", text] end)
  end
end
```

Comment: Edited to address your revised question :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. It looks a little verbose though, perhaps if this is needed for more than one location, it is a good candidate for a macro...

Comment: Code generation for this kind of task isn't necessary. I would extract that to a `merge_with_defaults(my_map, the_defaults)` func instead for reusability.

Comment: You should use Dict.merge/3 instead of Enum.into/3. I was going to add it as a comment but it was too big so I added another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well. I think you need to write another one `handle_my_map` function with argument `%{a: a, b: b}`. Like this:

```
  def handle_my_map(%{a: a, b: b, optional_c: c}) do
    a + b + c
  end

  def handle_my_map(%{a: a, b: b}) do
    a + b
  end

  YourModule.handle_my_map %{a: 1, b: 2}
  #=> 3
  YourModule.handle_my_map %{a: 1, b: 2, optional_c: 3}
  #=> 6
```

Elixir will search for a function `handle_my_map` which matches your arguments until functions with arity 1 end

Comment: Yes, but what if there are 5 optional parameters? I'd need 32 (`2^5`) implementations...

Comment: So you can not to use pattern matching. You can do something like this instead: 
`def handle_my_map(map), do: map[:a]+map[:b]+zero_if_nil (map[:optional_c])`, where `zero_if_nil/1` is another helper function.

Comment: Sad that `def method(%{a: a, b: b, c: c \\ default_c})` doesn't work. :(